# After \centering what is the best way to return to justified?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, errors, lists, ragged2e

Here is an over simplified example. My problem is the `\justify` and/or `\clearpage` creates an error on the first `\item` line saying "possible missing \item." I've used a similar sequence of code above this section without error; however, it was a table, text, another table. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of returning text after my `\centering` table or figure to be justified and look like the rest of my document. Also is the error occurring due to another package or is it the enumerate?

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}
Filler text is here. \\ 

\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Filler & Whatever \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}
\captionof{figure}{Filling for Figure}

\justify
\paragraph{Paragraph 2}
Filler Text


\centering
\captionof{table}{Table 1}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
x & 1  \\ 
\hline
y & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}

\clearpage %Adding this errors out
\justify %Or this

\paragraph{Paragraph 3} 
Filler text to show up.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Function
\item Filler Text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Edit 1: Made the document include proper packages.

Edit 2: The document now gives an error when including the 2 lines with comments. My overall goal is to have all three paragraphs, and the enumerated list justified as a 'normal' document does. The 2 tables and their captions should be centered as they are.

Comment: i can't say where the error messages are coming from, but to delimit the scope of `\centering` it can be surrounded by `\begingroup ... \endgroup`, `\bgroup ... \egroup`, or even just a brace pair `{...}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code does not compile; please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not sure that this working with the current situation. I've tried adding `\centering{....}` `{...\centering...}` and the `\bgroups....\egroup`.

Comment: @Enjuneer: You need {`\centering ... \par}`.

Comment: The correct syntax is `\justifying`, not `\justify`.

Comment: you could use `\justifying` but in practice `\centering` should always be used inside a group so you never need to explicitly return to justified text.

Comment: for a non floating table as in your example here  normally you would use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` so it is set off with some vertical space and the issue of `\centering` syntax does not arise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was told on a previous thread `\begin{center}....\end{center}` should be avoided but using it with non-floating tables/figures is ok? Using this would simplify life. 

`\justifying` did solve the issue too.

`\bgroup..\egroup` seemed to center the caption but not the table.

Comment: No you misunderstood you should use center here but in a real float like `\begin{table}` you should use `\centering` as `table` already adds vertical space. `\centering` needs a `\par` or blank line before the close group so you probably misused it when trying `}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

As has already been pointed out in comments, you should use `\justifying`, not `\justify` (that commands exists only because of a side-effect of how LaTeX implements the `justify` environment).